# Java scanner class - basic

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to let my user decide what to do by using the scanner class, but I have one issue, the code won't activate once it has already been run, and it won't let me skip any lines. My code looks like this:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (input.hasNextLine()){
        if (input.findInLine("setFirst") != null){
            System.out.println("setFirst");
        }else if(input.findInLine("setSecond") != null){
            System.out.println("setSecond");
        }else if (input.findInLine("setOption") != null){
            System.out.println("Please type in option.");
        }
    }
```

}

I thought the `hasNextLine()` would ensure that I could write any number of lines and it would be considered input?

Comment: It's not what you think. Refer to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine--).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do

Comment: @Johan Make it so that after the while loop has been executed once, it will execute once more if I type in for example "setFirst".

Comment: I updated my answer now. How do you want it to exitthe while loop so it won't get struck forever and ever ?:P

Comment: @Johan I'll just but in a break in one of the if-statements :)

Comment: Ok great! good luck! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try changing the code to this if I had understood you correctly:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str;

     while ((str = input.nextLine()) != null){

         if (str.equals("setFirst")){
             System.out.println("setFirst");
         }else if(str.equals("setSecond")){
             System.out.println("setSecond");
         } else if (str.equals("setOption")){
             System.out.println("Please type in option.");
         }

   }
```